# Converting JSON Data to String

Tags: javascript

Edit:  This first paragraph got cut off somehow during posting

I am a retired farmer not a coder.  I do dabble with html/js but am very far from competent at either.  What I am working on is modifying the html interface for my weather station.  It is for my own in house use only.  The JSON I am trying to use is hosted by the weather station software on an Raspberry pi on the URL listed a couple paragraphs down.

I will just post what I'm trying to do rather than anything about what I have tried.  The following code produces what I want - being able to add a temperature to an html page using the tag "extratemp".  It also truncates the sample temp from 69.0 to 69.

The sample data is actually contained in a JSON on the host computer (../api/extra/temp.json).  Again, my html page displays the desired "69" using the code below, I just cannot seem to replace the sample data (var str = line) with the live data from the JSON.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var str = '{"data":[["Sensor 1","69.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 2","0.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 3","0.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 4","0.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 5","0.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 6","0.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 7","0.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 8","0.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 9","0.0","&deg;F"],["Sensor 10","0.0","&deg;F"]]}'
  var jsonData = JSON.parse(str);
  document.getElementById("extratemp").textContent = Math.floor(jsonData.data[0][1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extratemp"></div>
```

Any help will be greately appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(obj);` JSON Data into String

Comment: @Nisarg What does that have to do with his question?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't get data from the file stored to the local disk to the browser's page. You need some kind of http server to serve your JSON file with results so the browser can request it and display the data on the page.

Comment: The title of your question is very misleading. Your question is about how to read JSON from a local file, nothing about converting the JSON data to a string.

Comment: As said above, JavaScript can't read directly from local files on the client machine. Can you move the file to a server?

Comment: @Barmar Initially I have read the title and it's misleading while reading actual question.

Comment: How are you trying to load the live data? Through an HTTP request to an API server running on the same computer (e.g. `$.get()`)? If you're trying to get it directly  from the file system, that won't work because the browser will protect your computer from websites trying to access its files.

Comment: From API server on same computer " (../api/extra/temp.json). "

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's getJSON function to download the JSON file & handle it by means a callback function:

```
$.getJSON( "../api/extra/temp.json", function( data ) { ... });
```

According with your data, the JSON object is an array of arrays, each item of the main array containig 3 values:

```
[ ["Sensor 1", "69.0", "&deg;F"], [...], ...]
```

Once again using jQuery library you can use the $each function to iterate thorugh each item of the main array, then accessing any particular subitem by index (0,1,2).

```
$.each(data, function( index, item ) {
  console.log("Item =>",  {item[0], item[1], item[2]} );
});
```

See: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/